# How can i extract values of bi grams from PyCaret topic modeler?

Tags: topic-modeling, pycaret

i have trained PyCaret topic modeler using the pycaret documentation https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/nlp.html#pycaret.nlp.get_topics

I am able to plot Bigrams using following code as mentioned in documentation

```
plot_model(plot = 'bigram',save = True)
```

Now i want to know how can i get the values of Bigrams so i can use them later in code etc.Any help would be greatly appreciated.